# Is Address Within GeoFilter

Tags: ios, swift, geofencing

I'm creating a delivery app in Swift and I am trying to restrict ordering to the state the user's in. I have geofenced the the state for the most part but, I am not sure if it is possible to check if:

- The Address the user inputs in the order field, is within the geofence.

Right now, I've reverse geocoded the address that the user inputs and they are being held within variables but, I don't see much documentation on this or how to go about checking. If you have any ideas on how to do this or if this is possible, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated to fence the irregular boundaries of a State. You could create a `CLPlacemark` from the coordinate geocoded from the user entered address. Then, access its `administrativeArea` variable to get the State.

```
var userLocation: CLLocation!

  // Then, when your view loads or elswhere:

        guard userLocation != nil else { return }

   // Geocode the location for setting the user placemark.
        let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation,
              completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let placemarks = placemarks,
                     placemarks.count > 0 else { return }
                self.setUserPlacemark(placemarks)
            }
        })
    }


   private func setUserPlacemark(_ placemarks: [CLPlacemark]) {


        guard (placemarks.count > 0) else { return }

        let placemark: CLPlacemark = placemarks[0]
        if placemark.administrativeArea != nil
        {
            // Do something with  placemark.administrativeArea  
         }
        }
```